# How to add dynamic texfield while clicking a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create textfield dynamically when I click checkbox in table. In table I have around 500 data. Each data has check box and user can search and select parameters. As below image, If user click Testing 1 checkbox from table, Same Testing1 value should present in Parameter name text field.

If the user selects Testing 2 checkbox, dynamically Textfield needs be added and Testing 2 value should be present in created textfield. If user uncheck checkbox, textfield has to be removed from table. I have attached snapshot for reference.

[image]

Below code for `TextField` which resides in table.

```html
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="protocol" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="span3 border-0" style="overflow: scroll">
      <table id="addParamTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr class="info">
            <th>Parameter Name</th>
            <th>Data Type</th>
            <th>Expected Set Value</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="parameter_table">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="parameterName" class="parameterName" name="parameter_name">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="parameterDscription" name="parameter_description">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="expectedValue" name="expected_value">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Are there 2 different tables, one with the checkboxes and another one in which the textfields/rows are added to?

Comment: What is the form of the data in your "testing 1, testing 2, testing 3" list? With this sort of work I would say both the checkboxes, the text fields, and the two tables where they are need to be generated from data, e.g. from a javascript array. Tell us about that data and how javascript could maintain it.

Comment: yes Matthias.Two different table."All Parameters table" loaded from database.Textfield created with one more table.

Comment: "testing 1, testing 2, testing 3" loading from data base."All Parameters table" loaded from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
$("#paramTable input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    let name = $(this).parent("td").next("td").text();
    let newname = name.replace(" ", "_");
    let newrow = $("<tr>");
    let newcell = $("<td>");
    let newinput = $("<input type='text' class='parameterName' name='" + newname + "' id='" + newname + "' value='" + name + "'/>");
    newcell.append(newinput);
    newrow.append(newcell);
    let newcells = $("<td><input type='text' class='parameterDscription' name='parameter_description'></td><td><input type='text' class='expectedValue' name='expected_value'></td>")
    newrow.append(newcells);
    $("tbody.parameter_table").append(newrow);
  } else {
    let name = $(this).parent("td").next("td").text();
    let newname = name.replace(" ", "_");
    $("#addParamTable").find("#" + newname).closest("tr").remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="paramTable">
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td>Testing 1</td>
  <td>1, 4, 6, 5, 9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td>Testing 2</td>
  <td>1, 4, 3, 5</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="protocol" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="span3 border-0" style="overflow: scroll">
      <table id="addParamTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr class="info">
            <th>Parameter Name</th>
            <th>Data Type</th>
            <th>Expected Set Value</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="parameter_table">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="parameterName" class="parameterName" name="parameter_name">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="parameterDscription" name="parameter_description">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="expectedValue" name="expected_value">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: @SubashiniRaja Glad that I was able to help :)

Comment: i am getting error.Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
_                Testting 1

Comment: function clickedParamBox(checkBoxName) {
    if ($(checkBoxName).is(":checked")) {

Comment: @SubashiniRaja It looks correct, but it might be an issue that you have a space in the value of id. You can try if($("input[@id='" + checkBoxName + "']"),is(":checked")) instead as it might work. Can you make a Fiddle with your current code?

Comment: now row is created but value is not coming matthis.showing empty values.Not deleted rows as well

Comment: html i am calling onclick="clickedBoxAddSnmp(this.name)"

Comment: function clickedBoxAddSnmp(checkBoxName) {
   
    if ($("input[name='" + checkBoxName + "']").is(":checked")) {
        let name = $("input[name='" + checkBoxName + "']").parent("td").next("td").next("td").text();

Comment: @SubashiniRaja Can you make a Fiddle with your current code? Not easy to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: It is working now Matthias.It is adding and deleting rows,But I have given SA (Select All)option also.It is working for single click.if i am clicking SA option it is creating single row only.

Comment: @SubashiniRaja You could do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1okzhy3w/

Comment: I am not able to delete rows Matthias now.I have changed values with your code.I want to print second column values instead of first column..Please check above fiddle

Comment: Can you plese check this Matthias. jsfiddle.net/pqab2z5h

Comment: I have adjusted your Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3v0zgb4q/ I changed the ids as the "," in the ids led to problems.

Comment: @SubashiniRaja Glad that I was able to help again :)

Comment: hi Mathhias,Sorry to trouble you.I have changed column value.Now again i am not able to delete rows.  https://jsfiddle.net/m8d0xe32/

Comment: One more change also i need to add.DataType column should be dropdown instead of textfield.I need to add values String,Boolean,Int,varchar in Dropdown/Select.For this i need to create separate new cell?

Comment: @SubashiniRaja It's working again here: https://jsfiddle.net/3smdhz84/ The problem was the "." in the ids. A version with the dropdown is here: https://jsfiddle.net/3smdhz84/1/

Comment: Matthias Can you please help on this?

Comment: @SubashiniRaja Help on what?

Comment: Sorry Matthias.I didn't' notice that you have replied. Thanks for your help

Comment: @SubashiniRaja No problem, glad that I was able to help again.

Comment: hi mattias.I have added Excution Type  as below

Comment: If i select Exec Type Datatype and Setvalue should be disabled.How to do this?Can you please help on this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348620/disable-and-enable-select-value-using-java-script

Comment: created as new question