# Disable and enable Select Value using Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using below code.If i click Testing 1 or Testing 2 or selectAll,new rows will be created.I need to disable  DatatType and Expected set value column if Execution Type is Get.If I select Set from Execution Type, DataType and Expected set value column should be enabled.How to implmente this?  I am using this code in Html.erb file.How to create separate js method?

https://jsfiddle.net/bx5fa2vu/

```
$("#all").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    let boxes = $("#paramTable input[type='checkbox']").not(this).not(":checked");
    boxes.each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  } else {
    let boxes = $("#paramTable input[type='checkbox']:checked").not(this);
    boxes.each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  }
});



$("#paramTable input[type='checkbox']:not(#all)").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    let name = $(this).parent("td").next("td").next("td").text().trim();
    let newname = name.split('.').join('');
    let newrow = $("<tr>");
    let newcell = $("<td> ");
    let newSel=$("<select class='ExeType' name='ExeTypeValue'><option value='getData'>Get</option><option value='SetData'>Set</option></select>")
    newcell.append(newSel);
        newrow.append(newSel);
    let newcell1 = $("<td> ");

    let newinput = $("<input type='text' class='parameterName' name='" + newname + "' id='" + newname + "' value='" + name + "'/>");
    newcell1.append(newinput);

    newrow.append(newcell1);
 let newcells = $("<td><select class='parameterDscription' name='parameter_description'><option value=''>Select Data Type</option><option value='OCTET_STRING'>String</option><option value='INTEGER'>Integer</option><option value='INTEGER32'>Unsigned Integer</option><option value='IPADDRESS'>IP Address</option><option value='x'>Hex String</option></select></td><td><input type='text' class='expectedValue' name='expected_value'></td>");
     newrow.append(newcells);
    $("tbody.parameter_table").append(newrow);
  } else {
    let name = $(this).parent("td").next("td").next("td").text();
    let newname = name.split('.').join('');
    console.log("newname: " + newname)
    $("#addParamTable").find("#" + newname).closest("tr").remove();
    $("#all").prop("checked", false);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. Note that initially the fields are not disabled because no value is selected at the Execution Type select field. Maybe you want to make this more clear by adding an initial option with the text "Select Type" to the select field like you have it for the select for Data Type.

```js
$("#all").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    let boxes = $("#paramTable input[type='checkbox']").not(this).not(":checked");
    boxes.each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  } else {
    let boxes = $("#paramTable input[type='checkbox']:checked").not(this);
    boxes.each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  }
});



$("#paramTable input[type='checkbox']:not(#all)").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    let name = $(this).parent("td").next("td").next("td").text().trim();
    let newname = name.split('.').join('');
    let newrow = $("<tr>");
    let newcell = $("<td> ");
    let newSel = $("<select class='ExeType' name='ExeTypeValue'><option value='getData'>Get</option><option value='SetData'>Set</option></select>")
    newcell.append(newSel);
    newrow.append(newSel);
    let newcell1 = $("<td> ");

    let newinput = $("<input type='text' class='parameterName' name='" + newname + "' id='" + newname + "' value='" + name + "'/>");
    newcell1.append(newinput);

    newrow.append(newcell1);
    let newcells = $("<td><select class='parameterDscription' name='parameter_description'><option value=''>Select Data Type</option><option value='OCTET_STRING'>String</option><option value='INTEGER'>Integer</option><option value='INTEGER32'>Unsigned Integer</option><option value='IPADDRESS'>IP Address</option><option value='x'>Hex String</option></select></td><td><input type='text' class='expectedValue' name='expected_value'></td>");
    newrow.append(newcells);
    $("tbody.parameter_table").append(newrow);
  } else {
    let name = $(this).parent("td").next("td").next("td").text();
    let newname = name.split('.').join('');
    console.log("newname: " + newname)
    $("#addParamTable").find("#" + newname).closest("tr").remove();
    $("#all").prop("checked", false);
  }
})

$(document).on("change", ".ExeType", function() {
  let type = $(this).val();
  if (type === "getData") {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".parameterDscription").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".expectedValue").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  } else {

    $(this).closest("tr").find(".parameterDscription").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".expectedValue").removeAttr("disabled");

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="paramTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="all" /></td>
    <td>Select all</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Testing 1</td>
    <td>1.2.3.4.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Testing 2</td>
    <td>.1.3.4.5.8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="protocol" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="span3 border-0" style="overflow: scroll">
      <table id="addParamTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr class="info">
                      <th>Excution Type</th>

            <th>Parameter Name</th>
            <th>Data Type</th>
            <th>Expected Set Value</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="parameter_table">
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I am trying to get value of Execution type value as below

Comment: for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var getOpereVal= rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
                var executionType = getOpereVal.options[getOpereVal.selectedIndex].value;}

Comment: I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined.How  to get execution type value. Matthias

Comment: Can you please help on this Matthias

Comment: It's solved here: https://jsfiddle.net/3grnkwsm/ You had a mistake at constructing the table, the select field wasn't in a <td> because you did newrow.append(newSel) instead of newrow.append(newcell).

Comment: Thanks Matthias :)

Comment: One more query i have.If i am using checkboxes,i can't select same oid multiple times.for instance i am selecting 1.2.3.4.5 oid,same oid i can't  select again.How to select same oid multiple times?

Comment: Can you please provide your suggestion Matthis?

Comment: @SubashiniRaja Can you please provide a Fiddle with your code?

Comment: Hi Matthias,I have created fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wcvL96nj/

Comment: I have added check box in table.My requirement is - if i click clone row,selected row will be cloned.If i click Delete row,selected row will be deleted.

Comment: Please help on the Matthias

Comment: @SubashiniRaja It's working here: https://jsfiddle.net/pqdkL0e1/

Comment: hi Matthias-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621003/launch-url-with-render-values-using-javascript

Comment: Can you please help on this?