# Java Script-Issue in creating dynamic rectangle in 10000 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created dynamically rectangles.I am able to create 7000 small rectangles.But if i am giving more than 10000 thousand it is showing blank screen only.What could be the reason for this?

```
class Rect extends lng.Application {
    static _template() {
        return {
            List: { type: RectTest }
        }
    }
    _init() {
        var n =10000;
        var rows = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));
        console.log(rows)
        var w = (window.innerWidth)/rows;
        var h = (window.innerHeight)/rows;
        var temp = []
        for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
          var color = ((1<<31)*Math.random()|1)
          var x = Math.floor(i%rows)*w;
          var y = Math.floor(i/rows)*h;
          temp[i] = [y,i,x,w,h,color]
        }
        this.tag('List').items = temp;
    }
    }   
class RectTest extends lng.Component {
    set items(items) {
        this.children = items.map((item, index) => {
            var value = item[1]
            return {
                rect:true,
                y: item[0], //y cordinate value
                x: item[2], //x cordinate value
                w: item[3], //width
                h: item[4], //height
                color: item[5]
            }
        })
    }
    
}

      app = new Rect ({stage: {w:window.innerWidth, h:window.innerHeight, clearColor: 0xFF000000}});
      document.body.appendChild(app.stage.getCanvas());
```

Comment: Please show us more code, I don't understand what you have and what you want.

Comment: make array of values. and iterate.

Comment: ok sure.How to launch url with different render values?

Comment: Post title doesn't reflect the problem, I suggest a rename

Comment: yes I have modified the Title

Comment: Which browsers have you tried?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox